# How to change the directory name used by Flash Builder 4.5 for actionscript project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a nicely working actionscript project in Flash Builder 4.5. However, I'd like to change the directory name that it sits in. Seems Flash Builder breaks if I manually change this directory name using the operating system. Is there a way to change this in Flash Builder so it doesn't get mad at me, or other workaround?

Comment: Which directory name do you want to change?  The source directory?  The bin directory?  Or the directory with the actual eclipse project files?

Comment: The project location directory. For example, the directory you select when you go from the Menu Bar: File > New > Actionscript Project, then under Project Location, there's a Folder input field with a Browse button. At least in Flash Builder 4.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just export it as an FXP, then reimport it. In the import wizard is an option to choose the folder to unzip the project into.

Answer (score 3):

With careful text editing I discovered it is possible to change the project path in the .location file underneath this directory:

```
Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\
```

It is a binary file, but the path was plain text. Saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 2):

I've just found another way to move a project. I'm using Flash Builder 4.5.

1) Select the project to move

2) In the context menu, choose the 7th option "move..."

3) Choose new location

4) You will be prompt for a progress of the copy of the project!

5) Relaunch the workspace, now all is ok, you can work on your project...

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project and select "Rename..."

Comment: I tried that, but this changes the project name, not the directory name that it sits in.

Comment: Hmm, when I do it, it changes both.  Odd that you're seeing different behavior.

Comment: Yah, I tried it again, no luck. I'm on Mac OS (snow leopard).

Comment: Hrm, I'm on Lion.  I'm using the FB plugin instead of bundled though, maybe it's a difference in the Eclipse version.  Sorry I don't have a ready answer for you.

Comment: Funny, I resisted Lion because I thought I'd have a more stable environment for Adobe's products. Thanks anyway blahdiblah. Maybe someone else has an idea...